# How to connect to SQL Server from a Windows 10 home computer?

Tags: sql-server

I have a server in my LAN that has SQL Server 2017 installed. I have a laptop that uses Windows 10 Home, and I would like to connect to a database on that SQL Server.

The Windows 10 is a windows 10 home edition, so it is not possible to join a domain, so by the moment to can connect to SQL Server, I have created a user in the server that it has the same user name and password than the user on the Windows 10 computer. I am mirroring the user, I think it is called in this way.

But this make me to have to change the password manually each time the user of the Windows 10 computer changes the password in his computer, and it can use any password, it has to follow the rules of the windows server.

So I am wondering if it would be a better option to can connect to the database from the windows 10 computer and manage the permissions.

Thanks.

Comment: Either upgrade to Pro, or use SQL Authentication? if you want to use AD Authenication you need Pro. If you don't can't use AD Authentication use SQL Authentication.

Comment: You can connect to SQL server from IIS or Windows Excel if not then OpenOffice`s Spreadsheet with ODBC connection driver. I prefer IIS, because it comes with Windows 10, just Enable it and you can also launch and manage your Web applications from IIS.